# react-router-dom v4 Redirect to programatically

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a `UserLogin` component which will send a request and upon response I want to redirect to the `AfterLogin` component.

```
if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // success
                this.context.history.push('/dashboard')
            }
```

After a lot of search my react-router-dom v4 Router looks like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Router forceRefresh={false} history={history}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                    Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                        <DashboardPage/>
                    ) : (
                        <LoginPage/>
                    )
                )}/>
                <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => (
                    Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                        <DashboardPage/>
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to="/login"/>
                    )
                )}/>
                <Route path="/login" render={() => (
                    Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                        <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
                    ) : (
                        <LoginPage/>
                    )
                )}/>
                <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Everything is working perfectly fine, except the `this.context.history.push('/dashboard')`part. How do I redirect the user after login? By using that method I see in the console that `this.context` is not defined.

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: You should use props instead of context, like `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`. Where do you call `this.context...` right now?

Comment: Inside the UserLogin component, after a user submitted the form and got back ok from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which properties of context you want your component to have access to. Supposing your xhr request is inside your UserLogin component you will need to add the following to access context.history.

```
UserLogin.contextTypes = {
    history: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

But you should not use context, rather you should use React Routers `withRouter` function which will put `history` on props of your component.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class UserLogin extends React.Component { ... }

// can call history with this.props.history in UserLogin now
export default withRouter(UserLogin);
```

Comment: I see that in the docs they're using `PropTypes`, but when I try to do the same I get `duplicate declaration of "PropTypes"`. Could you provide a response that includes the constructor and the use of `PropTypes`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Who is using prop types ? Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: Found the problem. Thank you. I was importing the `PropTypes` from `react` too and basically they were being imported twice, once from the new `PropTypes` module and once from React.